# Accessing ViewBag within _LogOnPartial in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying to pass in data after valid logon to the _LogOnParial view but ViewBag isn't accessible.  How can I pass in data to this partial view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data between controller action methods use TempData or send it over as a parameter in the Html.Partial call from using a viewmodel or viewdata to make the data available to send as a parameter in the Partial call.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like _LogonPartial is getting called in multiple places and TempData eventually is out of scope.  How can I persist some user information the entire session?

Comment: Using the session object or caching information based on some key specific to the user OR storing the information in the users forms authentication ticket.